# Reset Timeline of animation  - blender 2.6

Tags: blender, blender-2.50, blender-2.61

I am new to Blender animation, i have simple 3d model which has bones to animate and its animating as expected, now what i want to do is reset the frames in timeline of the blender, for exampe, my animation loop is between 250 to 300 frames and want to shift the same starting from zero and reset/delete rest of the frames. - Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope I understood your problem. Go to [DopeSheet](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/Dopesheet) view in mode *Dope Sheet* or *Action Editor* and mark the frames you want to shift using the same keys like in other windows e.g. a for all b for box select c,... Then just g for grab.

If you want to create a new action you can copy the selected frames with Ctrl-C and paste them at another place even into a new action.